# Is there a way to avoid Rate Limit Error in Twitter API in my python program?

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to create a Twitter user graph and for that I have written the following code :

```
import operator
import sys
import time
from urllib.error import URLError
from http.client import BadStatusLine
import json
import twitter
from functools import partial
from sys import maxsize as maxint
import itertools
import networkx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = networkx.Graph()


# Code and function taken from the twitter cookbook
def oauth_login():
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxZD6r'
    OAUTH_TOKEN = 'xxNRYl'
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxHYJl'
    auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
    return twitter_api


# Code and function taken from the twitter cookbook
def make_twitter_request(twitter_api_func, max_errors=10, *args, **kw):
    # A nested helper function that handles common HTTPErrors. Return an updated
    # value for wait_period if the problem is a 500 level error. Block until the
    # rate limit is reset if it's a rate limiting issue (429 error). Returns None
    # for 401 and 404 errors, which requires special handling by the caller.
    def handle_twitter_http_error(e, wait_period=2, sleep_when_rate_limited=True):
        if wait_period > 3600:  # Seconds
            print('Too many retries. Quitting.', file=sys.stderr)
            raise e
        if e.e.code == 401:
            print('Encountered 401 Error (Not Authorized)', file=sys.stderr)
            return None
        elif e.e.code == 404:
            print('Encountered 404 Error (Not Found)', file=sys.stderr)
            return None
        elif e.e.code == 429:
            print('Encountered 429 Error (Rate Limit Exceeded)', file=sys.stderr)
            if sleep_when_rate_limited:
                print("Retrying in 15 minutes...ZzZ...", file=sys.stderr)
                sys.stderr.flush()
                time.sleep(60 * 15 + 5)
                print('...ZzZ...Awake now and trying again.', file=sys.stderr)
                return 2
            else:
                raise e  # Caller must handle the rate limiting issue
        elif e.e.code in (500, 502, 503, 504):
            print('Encountered {0} Error. Retrying in {1} seconds'.format(e.e.code, wait_period), file=sys.stderr)
            time.sleep(wait_period)
            wait_period *= 1.5
            return wait_period
        else:
            raise e

    wait_period = 2
    error_count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            return twitter_api_func(*args, **kw)
        except twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError as e:
            error_count = 0
            wait_period = handle_twitter_http_error(e, wait_period)
            if wait_period is None:
                return
        except URLError as e:
            error_count += 1
            time.sleep(wait_period)
            wait_period *= 1.5
            print("URLError encountered. Continuing.", file=sys.stderr)
            if error_count > max_errors:
                print("Too many consecutive errors...bailing out.", file=sys.stderr)
                raise
        except BadStatusLine as e:
            error_count += 1
            time.sleep(wait_period)
            wait_period *= 1.5
            print("BadStatusLine encountered. Continuing.", file=sys.stderr)
            if error_count > max_errors:
                print("Too many consecutive errors...bailing out.", file=sys.stderr)
                raise


# Code and function taken from the twitter cookbook
def get_friends_followers_ids(twitter_api, screen_name=None, user_id=None,
                              friends_limit=maxint, followers_limit=maxint):
    # Must have either screen_name or user_id (logical xor)
    assert (screen_name is not None) != (user_id is not None), "Must have screen_name or user_id, but not both"

    # See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get- 
    #users/api-reference/get-friends-ids for details
    # on API parameters

    get_friends_ids = partial(make_twitter_request, twitter_api.friends.ids, count=5000)
    get_followers_ids = partial(make_twitter_request, twitter_api.followers.ids, count=5000)
    friends_ids, followers_ids = [], []
    for twitter_api_func, limit, ids, label in [
        [get_friends_ids, friends_limit, friends_ids, "friends"],
        [get_followers_ids, followers_limit, followers_ids, "followers"]
    ]:
        if limit == 0: continue
        cursor = -1
        while cursor != 0:
            # Use make_twitter_request via the partially bound callable...
            if screen_name:
                response = twitter_api_func(screen_name=screen_name, cursor=cursor)
            else:  # user_id
                response = twitter_api_func(user_id=user_id, cursor=cursor)
            if response is not None:
                ids += response['ids']
                cursor = response['next_cursor']
            print('Fetched {0} total {1} ids for {2}'.format(len(ids), label, (user_id or screen_name)),
                  file=sys.stderr)
            # XXX: You may want to store data during each iteration to provide an
            # an additional layer of protection from exceptional circumstances
            if len(ids) >= limit or response is None:
                break
    # Do something useful with the IDs, like store them to disk...
    return friends_ids[:friends_limit], followers_ids[:followers_limit]


# Code and function taken from the twitter cookbook
def get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=None, user_ids=None):
    # Must have either screen_name or user_id (logical xor)
    assert (screen_names is not None) != (user_ids is not None)
    items_to_info = {}
    items = screen_names or user_ids
    while len(items) > 0:
        items_str = ','.join([str(item) for item in items[:100]])
        items = items[100:]
        if screen_names:
            response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, screen_name=items_str)
        else:  # user_ids
            response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, user_id=items_str)
        for user_info in response:
            if screen_names:
                items_to_info[user_info['screen_name']] = user_info
            else:  # user_ids
                items_to_info[user_info['id']] = user_info
    return items_to_info


# Function to find reciprocal friends and sort them such that we get the top 5 friends
def reciprocal_friends(twitter_api, screen_name=None, user_id=None):
    friends_list_ids, followers_list_ids = get_friends_followers_ids(twitter_api, screen_name=screen_name,
                                                                     user_id=user_id,
                                                                     friends_limit=5000, followers_limit=5000)
    friends_reciprocal = list(set(friends_list_ids) & set(followers_list_ids))
    list_followers_count = []
    user_profiles = {}
    for each in friends_reciprocal:
        user_profiles[each] = get_user_profile(twitter_api, user_ids=[each])[each]
        list_followers_count.append(user_profiles[each]['followers_count'])
    res = sorted(list_followers_count, reverse=True)
    friends_count = {user_profiles[fr]['followers_count']: fr for fr in friends_reciprocal}
    list_resciprocal = []
    if len(res) < 6:
        list_resciprocal = friends_reciprocal
    else:
        for i in range(5):
            list_resciprocal.append(friends_count[res[i]])
    return list_resciprocal


# This function finds reciprocal friends again and again till we achieve at least 100 nodes
def crawler(twitter_api, screen_name=None, user_id=None):
    rec_friends = reciprocal_friends(twitter_api, screen_name=screen_name, user_id=user_id)
    edges = [(screen_name, x) for x in rec_friends]
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    nodes = nxt_qu = rec_friends
    if len(nodes) == 0:
        print("No reciprocal friends")
        return rec_friends
    while G.number_of_nodes() < 101:
        print("Queue Items : ", nxt_qu)
        (queue, nxt_qu) = (nxt_qu, [])
        for q in queue:
            if G.number_of_nodes() >= 101:
                break
            print("ID Entered:", q)
            res = reciprocal_friends(twitter_api, screen_name=None, user_id=q)
            edges = [(q, z) for z in res]
            G.add_edges_from(edges)
            nxt_qu += res
            nodes += res
    print(nodes)

    # To Plot the graph
    networkx.draw(G)
    plt.savefig("graphresult.png")
    plt.show()

    # Printing the Output
    print("No. of Edges: ", G.number_of_edges())
    print("No. of Nodes: ", G.number_of_nodes())
    print("Diameter : ", networkx.diameter(G))
    print("Average Distance: ", networkx.average_shortest_path_length(G))

    # To write the output into a file
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    f.write("No. of Nodes: " + str(G.number_of_nodes()))
    f.write("\nNo. of Edges: " + str(G.number_of_edges()))
    f.write("\nDiameter: " + str(networkx.diameter(G)))
    f.write("\nAverage Distance: " + str(networkx.average_shortest_path_length(G)))


twitter_api = oauth_login()
crawler(twitter_api, screen_name="POTUS")
```

However I am getting this error often and this is making my program run very slow

ID Entered: 60784269
Fetched 5000 total friends ids for 60784269
Fetched 5000 total followers ids for 60784269
Encountered 429 Error (Rate Limit Exceeded)
Retrying in 15 minutes...ZzZ...

Is there a way to get around this ? Make the code run faster ?
I have read a few documents but I still dont have any clear picture. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to go around the rate limits restrictions with the Public API.

Though there is an API v2 now which also allow you to get users and do not work against the same rate limits.

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/introduction

Notice that this solution would be temporary as Twitter will at some point remove access to API v1.

You can request twitter to have access to premium/enterprise level of the API but you will have to pay for that.

You can see rate limits documentation here :

- [API v1](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits)
- [API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits)